Can we form a carbon free radical by providing a carbocation an electron?
MY teacher told me this but I was not satisfied by the answer

What was the answer that your teacher provided? Can you include that in your post?

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Stable carbocations can act as single electron oxidisers, becoming radicals in the process.
